# Where and how to buy Petro?

Tags: altcoin, ico-initial-coin-offering

The Venezuela is about to launch the pre-sale (at 12:30pm GMT) of its [Petro cryptocurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petro_(cryptocurrency)).

For that, they release a [buyer manual](http://elpetro.gob.ve/docs/MANUAL%20COMPRADOR%20VERSION%20BETA.pdf) in Spanish. Do you know where I could find the document translated in English? What is the procedure for participating in the pre-sale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not make an effort to look for it, it has not started the sale yet and the website is down (http://www.elpetro.gob.ve)

Answer (score 3):

The presale is available for venezuelan citizens for the moment only paíd in euros, dollars , btc and eth

Answer (score 1):

I received the first email from the Venezuelan government. I also translated the Spanish guide fully (pretty simple steps). In the email I was led to a link that asked me the minimum and maximum I would purchase. I am currently waiting for the second email to download the wallet. If anyone has surpassed this point and actually gotten the wallet let me know.